# portable way to create a timestamp in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I need to generate time-stamp in this format yyyymmdd. Basically I want to create a filename with current date extension. (for example: log.20100817)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  char date[9];
  time_t t = time(0);
  struct tm *tm;

  tm = gmtime(&t);
  strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%Y%m%d", tm);
  printf("log.%s\n", date);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `tm` temporary - you could just pass the return value of `gmtime(&t)` straight to `strftime()`.

Comment: @caf: I think the point is to show what `gmtime` returns. Typically you wouldn't just print it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative: [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time.html).

Answer (score 1):

A modern `C++` answer:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string create_timestamp()
{
    auto current_time = std::time(nullptr);
    tm time_info{};
    const auto local_time_error = localtime_s(&time_info, &current_time);
    if (local_time_error != 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("localtime_s() failed: " + std::to_string(local_time_error));
    }
    std::ostringstream output_stream;
    output_stream << std::put_time(&time_info, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M");
    std::string timestamp(output_stream.str());
    return timestamp;
}
```

All the format code are detailed on the [`std::put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) page.