# Get start of day timestamp c++

Tags: c++, time, timestamp, c++-chrono

I need to get timestamp in c++. I've found some functions in `chrono` for example:

```
 std::chrono::system_clock::now()
```

But it's returning current time. How to get timestamp for a day? I mean the time that represents 00:00:00 of today and the same for yesterday? I'm very new to c++..

Comment: So, why'd you tag [tag:C]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [portable way to create a timestamp in c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505352/portable-way-to-create-a-timestamp-in-c-c)

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456449/193789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you just need date, without time. So, you can get it like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto curr = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto tm = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(curr);
    cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&tm), "%d.%m.%Y");
}
```

and, of course, you can forcibly reset the fields of time, if you need:

```
    auto curr = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    time_t tm = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(curr);
    auto lt = std::localtime(&tm);
    lt->tm_hour = 0;
    lt->tm_min = 0;
    lt->tm_sec = 0;   
    cout << lt->tm_mday << "." << lt->tm_mon + 1 << "." << lt->tm_year + 1900 << endl;
```

Comment: thank you! Do you know how to get localtime of yesterday?

Comment: _tm = tm - (24*60*60); auto lt = std::localtime(&tm);_

Comment: cool! and the last question, how to convert it to unix timestamp?

Comment: _tm_ this is it. It stores timestamp as seconds since 1970

Comment: tm is a struct, not a timestamp